# Print just the one line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been practising and getting more and more into Python and have written a script that asks if users have "already registered", if so then the program checks if they have been reading each line of a text file and verifies their details and if not then they register.

Pretty much everything is working bar this one frustrating bit were when a user selects yes they're already a member and asked for the details they used to register, if the user enters in their details successfully it runs through each line in the for loop and prints either one of the if statements. Is there anyway to get it to print out "Yes you're already registered" or "Sorry you haven't registered yet registered" just the one time instead of going through each line and printing a result out for each line?

Thanks again everyone...

```
def find_me():
    print("\nPlease enter your details below \n")
    fn = input("Please enter first name ").upper()
    ln = input("Please enter last name ").upper()
    em = input("Please enter email ")
    mo = input("Please enter mobile ")
    read_file = open("users.txt", "r")
    file_array = read_file.readlines()

    q = fn + " " + ln + " " + em + " " + mo

    for whole_join in file_array:
        new_join = whole_join.split()
        x = " ".join(new_join)
        #print(x)
        #print(q)


        if str(x) == str(q):
            print("\nYes you're already registered\n")
            break
        elif str(x) != str(q):
            print("\nSorry you haven't registered yet registered\n")
```

Comment: Make the `elif` an `else` of the `for`. [for/else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this seems to be a good time use the

```
for ... in ...:
    ...
else:
   ....
```

construct.  The else portion of the for loop will execute if no break was encountered during the looping.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to add a flag variable, but I think @Christian Sloper's answer looks better :D

```
 found_user = false
 for whole_join in file_array:
        new_join = whole_join.split()
        x = " ".join(new_join)

        if str(x) == str(q):
            found_user = true
            break

if found_user:
    print("\nYes you're already registered\n")
else:
    print("\nSorry you haven't registered yet registered\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for whole_join in file_array:
    new_join = whole_join.split()
    x = " ".join(new_join)
    if str(x) == str(q):
        print("\nYes you're already registered\n")
        break
else:
    print("\nSorry you haven't registered yet\n")
```

Thank you both, i got it working with......^^^^ Does that seem correct?